# Configure Artifact in Intellij to create a war file

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea, jboss, war

So assume I have a Java Project in Intellij. My goal is to export it as a war file and run it in a docker container using jboss. I am using the Intellij ultimate version, so I do have this option of creating a war file. Those are my steps: I first created a new artifact (Web application: Archive) and did not change any of the default settings. Then I went on the build option and simply built the artifact, however I can't seem to get any war file. The only thing new is in the .idea/artifacts/ folder and it is an XML File that looks like this:

```
<component name="ArtifactManager">
  <artifact type="war" name="unnamed">
    <output-path>$PROJECT_DIR$/out/artifacts/unnamed</output-path>
    <root id="archive" name="unnamed.war" />
  </artifact>
</component>
```

Normally the war file should then be saved in the out/artifacts/ folder but it simply doesn't exist. Something I was thinking about when creating the artifact was that it said "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file not found in 'unnamed.war'" and then I have the options "Create Manifest" and "Use existing Manifest". Could this help me somehow?

I am testing this with a simple Hello World program that only has the main class but also need it to work for a big project in the future.
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any errors/warnings in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: @y.bedrov Here is my entire log: https://pastebin.com/F92RqA8z As far as I can tell there are a few warnings but no errors

Comment: Please try to add manifest and module compile output to artifact.